# opponet can't apply a move in python mulitplayer Tic-Tac-Toe

Tags: python, sockets

so I was basically was trying to make a multiplayer Tic-Tac-Toe game but then I've been  running into this following problems

This is the host side:

```
Enter row and column numbers to fix spot(row,column): 1,2
- X -
- - -
- - -
```

This is the guest side:

```
X - -
- - -
- - -
```

The problems are:

1. It did not pass the turn to the guest side.
2. It displays a false mark
   on the grid.

```py
import socket
import threading


HOST = '192.168.1.115'
PORT = 9090


class TicTacToe:
    def __init__(self):
        self.you = 'O'
        self.opponet = 'X'
        self.turn = 'X'
        self.board = []
        self.game_over = False
        self.winner = None
        self.counter = 0
        self.create_board()

    def create_board(self):
        for i in range(3):
            row = []
            for j in range(3):
                row.append('-')
            self.board.append(row)

    def show_board(self):
        for row in self.board:
            for item in row:
                print(item, end=" ")
            print()

    def is_board_filled(self):
        for row in self.board:
            for item in row:
                if item == '-':
                    return False
        return True


    def fix_move(self, row, col, player):
        if self.game_over:
            return

        self.counter +=1
        self.board[row-1][col-1] = player
        self.show_board()

        if self.is_player_win(player):
            if self.winner == self.you:
                print('You win!')
                exit()
            if self.winner == self.opponet:
                print('You lose!')
                exit()
        else:
            if self.counter == 9:
                print('Its a draw!')
                exit()

                

    def valid_move(self, row, col):
        if self.board[row][col] == 'O' or self.board[row][col] == 'X':
            return False
        return True

    def swap_player_turn(self):
        self.turn =  self.you if self.turn == self.opponet else self.opponet

    def handle(self, client):
        while not self.game_over:
            if self.turn == self.you:            
                move = input("Enter row and column numbers to fix spot(row,column): ")
                place = move.split(',')
                if self.valid_move(int(place[0]), int(place[1])):
                    self.fix_move(int(place[0]), int(place[1]), self.you)
                    self.turn = self.opponet
                    client.send(move.encode('utf-8'))
                else:
                    print('Invalid Move!')
            else:
                data = client.recv(1024)
                if not data:
                    client.close()
                    break
                else:
                    place = data.decode('utf-8').split(',')
                    self.fix_move(int(place[0]), int(place[0]), self.opponet)
        client.close()

    def is_player_win(self, player):
        if self.board[0][0] == self.board[0][1] == self.board[0][2] == 'X':
            return  True
        if self.board[1][0] == self.board[1][1] == self.board[1][2] == 'X' or 'O':
            return  True
        if self.board[2][0] == self.board[2][1] == self.board[2][2] == 'X' or 'O':
            return  True
         # etc etc
        
    def host_game(self, host, port):
        server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        server.bind((host, port))
        server.listen(1)

        client, addr = server.accept()
        self.you = 'X'
        self.opponet = 'O'
        threading.Thread(target=self.handle, args=(client,)).start()
        server.close()

    def connect_to_game(self, host, port):
        client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        client.connect((host, port))

        self.you = 'O'
        self.opponet = 'X'
        threading.Thread(target=self.handle, args=(client,)).start()


game = TicTacToe()
game.host_game(HOST, PORT)
```

the structure of the code is in a way that you take the source code above and copy it and  then generate 2 files, one for the host and another for the guest the difference between them is that you you use the `host_game` function  in the host file and the `connect_to_game` function in the guest file.

I've tried everything I could , searching in here , googling and nothing
I've also tried to ask ChatGPT but it was worthless

Answer (score 2):

I'll address the immediate two problems:

1. Use your `swap_player_turn()` method and place it at the bottom of the `while` loop in `handle` so it happens on both host and client after the turn is handled.  This will pass the turn correctly.
2. After asking for input or receiving data, call a common a function to convert to 0-based row/col data, because sometimes you subtract one from row/col, and sometimes you don't.  For example:

   ```
   def parse_move(move):
       return [int(n)-1 for n in move.split(',')]

   move = input("Enter row and column numbers to fix spot(row,column): ")
   row, col = parse_move(move)

   ...

   data = client.recv(1024)
   row, col = parse_move(move)
   ```

   Then use row/col instead of `int(place[n])` everywhere.  This will fix the false mark.

Other issues are the code isn't complete to determine a win or draw, `opponet` is misspelled, and (while this slow turn-based code will probably never have the issue) TCP is not a message-based protocol, but the code assumes it is.

A useful debug feature is to make the game able to print its state.  For example, add:

```
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'TicTacToe(you={self.you!r}, op={self.opponent!r}, turn={self.turn!r})'
```

Then `print(self)` at the top of the while loop.